# How to Unit Test Methods with Sharepoint Objects as parameters with Microsoft Fakes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sharepoint, microsoft-fakes

Im trying to write a unit test for methods that take sp objects as parameters like SPWeb or SPEventReceiverCollection etc. with Microsoft Fakes but have no idea how to mock these. 
I've used moq before but cant seem to find how to Mock in microsoft fakes. 
eg:

```
public List<SPEventReceiverDefinition> CheckExisting(SPEventReceiverDefinitionCollection recs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Fakes.ShimSPEventReceiverDefinition fakeERD = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Fakes.ShimSPEventReceiverDefinition();

        fakeERD.TypeGet = () => { return type; };
        fakeERD.AssemblyGet = () => { return assembly; };
        fakeERD.ClassGet = () => { return Constants.UsernameWriterPath; };
```

Figured it out. The areas where the Fake classes are used also need to be in a ShimContext.
Above example goes shows how to create and set the object / properties.

```
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {//testing code goes here}
```